# Sum of prime numbers between a given interval

Tags: python

**Instead of the sum of prime numbers the output is the sum of all the numbers between the interval**
Here is my code:

```
x=int(input("lower limit"))
y=int(input("upper limit"))
s=0
for i in range(x, y+1):
    for j in range(2,int(i ** (0.5))+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    s += i
print(s)
```

Comment: I dont understand what your `j` loop is for? You are doing `s+=i` regardless of the inner loop

Comment: Just a logic error. In any case, (break or end of the 2nd `for` loop), the statement `s += i` will be executed.

Comment: j loop is checking if i has any factors other that 1 and the number itself.

Comment: true.. But `s +=i` happens whether your factors are found or not. This is indeed a logic error.

Comment: Shouldn't break move the  pointer to the next value of i?

Comment: `break` exits the inner loop. That does not affect value of `i` or the `s+=i` statement

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding `i` on every loop iteration(whether there are any factors other than 1 and itself). Instead, add `i` only when the factor is 1 and `i`:

```
x=int(input("lower limit"))
y=int(input("upper limit"))
s=0
for i in range(x, y+1):
    for j in range(2,int(i ** (0.5))+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        s += i
print(s)
```

Output:

```
lower limit2
upper limit10
17
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a variable `found` which we reset to 0 before each number tested.

```
x=int(input("lower limit"))
y=int(input("upper limit"))
s=0
for i in range(x, y+1):
    found=0
    for j in range(2,int(i ** (0.5))+1):
        if i % j == 0:
           found=1
    if found==0:
        print("adding",i)
        s += i
print(s)
```

Example run

```
lower limit2
upper limit7
adding 2
adding 3
adding 5
adding 7
17
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem with your code, making it harder to debug, is that it is not divided into functions.

Your basic operation is checking if a number is prime, so you should define a function `is_prime` checking if an integer is prime.

```
def is_prime(n):
    for j in range(2,int(i ** (0.5))+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Once you have a function, you can test it and check if it works.

After that, you can use your building block and create a more readable and debuggable code:

```
x=int(input("lower limit"))
y=int(input("upper limit"))
s=0

for i in range(x, y+1):
    if is_prime(i):
        s += i

print(s)
```

If can use external packages, there's an implementation for `is_prime` in the packages `sympy` and `primePy` - comparing your results to these implementations is also a good way to test your code.